Prove $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(2n-1)x^2+a(4n-2)x+2na^2-b}{\left(x^2+2ax+b\right)^{n+1}}\operatorname dx=0.$

Let $a$, $b$ be real numbers such that $a^2<b$, and $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(2n-1)x^2+a(4n-2)x+2na^2-b}{\left(x^2+2ax+b\right)^{n+1}}\operatorname dx=0.$$

My idea is to let
$$f(b)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(2n-1)x^2+a(4n-2)x+2na^2-b}{\left(x^2+2ax+b\right)^{n+1}}\operatorname dx.$$
Then it suffices to prove that

$f^\prime(b)=0$ (implying that $f(b)$ is a constant function)
There exists $b_0$ such that $f(b_0)=0$ (concluding that $f(b)\equiv0$)

But I don't know how to prove either of them.

Also, I would like to know whether $a^2<b$ and $n\in\Bbb N_+$ are necessary.

Do you know how to differentiate under the integral sign with respect to a parameter?

@insipidintegrator I don't know how to do that.

The restriction $a^2 < b$ arises because we require the discriminant of the quadratic factor in the denominator to be negative, so that the integrand does not have any singularities on the real line.
Note the indefinite integral has an elementary closed form:  observe
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{x+a}{(x^2 + 2ax + b)^n}\right]
&=\frac{2n(x+a)^2(x^2 + 2ax + b)^{n-1} - (x^2 + 2ax + b)^n}{(x^2 + 2ax + b)^{2n}} \\
&= \frac{2n(x+a)^2-x^2-2ax-b}{(x^2+2ax+b)^{n+1}} \\
&= -\frac{(2n-1)x^2 + a(4n-2)x + 2na^2 - b}{(x^2+2ax+b)^{n+1}}.
\end{align}$$
So $$\begin{align}
\int \frac{(2n-1)x^2 + a(4n-2)x + 2na^2 - b}{(x^2+2ax+b)^{n+1}} \, dx 
&= -\frac{x+a}{(x^2+2ax+b)^n} + C.
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{x=-N}^N \frac{(2n-1)x^2 + a(4n-2)x + 2na^2 - b}{(x^2+2ax+b)^{n+1}} \, dx = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{-N+a}{(N^2-2aN+b)^n} -\frac{N+a}{(N^2+2aN+b)^n}.$$
Since there are no singularities, this limit evaluates to $0$.  Hence the condition $a^2 < b$ is required, although $n$ need not be an integer; it may be any real greater than $1/2$.

Heroic calculations, bravo.

Admirable "note". Did you find it by perception?

@youthdoo I found it by trying to express the integrand in terms of a quotient rule derivative of the form $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{f(x)}{g(x)^n}\right] = \frac{f(x) ng(x)^{n-1} g'(x) - f'(x) g(x)^n}{g(x)^{2n}} = \frac{n f(x)g'(x) - f'(x) g(x)}{g(x)^{n+1}}$$ where $g(x) = x^2 + 2ax + b$ was the natural choice.  So it was sort of trial and error.

Hint Substitute $x = c u - a$ to transform the integral to
$$c^{1 - 2n} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{(2 n - 1) u^2 - 1}{(u^2 + 1)^{n + 1}} \,du,$$ where $c^2 = b - a^2$, $c > 0$. But this latter integrand has a simple antiderivative that decays to $0$ as $u \to \pm \infty$.

 $$\int \frac{(2 n - 1) u^2 - 1}{(u^2 + 1)^{n + 1}} \,du = -\frac{u}{(u^2 + 1)^n} + C$$

Remark In fact, this argument shows that the result holds for any real $n > \frac12$.
If $b - a^2 \leq 0$ then the original integral has nonintegrable singularities at $\pm \sqrt{a^2 - b}$, and so in that case the integral does not converge.

Use the change of variable $y=(x-a)/k$ where $k=\sqrt{b-a^2}$, then $y=\tan \theta$ then
$$2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\sin \theta)^{2p-1}(\cos \theta)^{2q-1}d\theta=\frac{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(q)}{\Gamma(p+q)}.$$

Could you give some  more details?

On which point?

I mean the equal sign before the gamma functions.

just do $x=\sin^2 \theta$ for landing on the classical beta Euler function. This is a classical and useful formula.  I ackowledge that the method for solving your problem is not inventive, but while training students,  I always try technique before creativity
